# register new user from api route using laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, api, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I have installed **laravel 5.3** and **passport pakage**.
I followed the documentaition step by step
I can use the following route `POST /oauth/token` with the following parameters

1. username
2. password
3. client_secret
4. grant_type
5. client_id

and I get the following response

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 31536000,
  "access_token": "access token here",
  "refresh_token": "refresh token here"
}
```

then I request `GET /api/user`

with the following header

1. Authorization = "Bearer access token here"
2. accept = application/json (optional)

and this is work fine and so all apis.

the problem I have is the user who I authinticated and entered his username and password in the first request and return me back the access token is a user I have created from laravel web view /register

How can I create new user or register new user from the api route file

like `POST /api/register`

the user at first time need to register to be authinticated after that.

Should I create this route without oauth to register then if success the registration he request `POST /oauth/token` to be authinticated or what? 
Am I missing something ??

**update** 
the `clent_secret` is it right to be constant in all users requests or each user should have diffrent clent_secret, and if it is how to create aclent secret if it neaded to authinticate user ?

Comment: you can register a user by adding it to the user table... no need to do anything with passport, then when you want to retrieve the access token call the login function, regarding the client_secret i personally use one for all users, to create it `php artisan passport:install`

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to do this is adding an exception to your verifyCsrfToken.php class

```
protected $except = [
        'register'
    ];
```

Then you can post to your register model, and afterwards accessing this account with oauth/token.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to register new user and get token after registration from `/oauth/token`. For this you can use a proxy. I have used something similar and i followed the following steps. This works for both Login and Register

1. Register the user and send a HTTP request to `/oauth/token` endpoint from your register method

   ```
   public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
   {
       $user = User::create($request->all());

       $response = $this->authenticationProxy->attemptLogin($request->email, $request->password);
       return response()->json(compact('response', 'user'), 201);
   }
   ```
2. Then in your `proxy` class, call the `/oauth/token`

   ```
   public function attemptLogin($email, $password)
   {
       $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

       $response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
           'form_params' => [
               'grant_type' => 'password',
               'client_id' => env('CLIENT_ID'),
               'client_secret' => env('CLIENT_SECRET'),
               'username' => $email,
               'password' => $password,
               'scope' => '',
           ],
       ]);

       return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true); 
   }
   ```

Hope this helps. You can use similar approach for login as well.